# ¿Cómo ordenar List en Java teniendo en cuenta las tildes?

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8

Tengo un problema que no he podido solucionar buscando en internet. Tengo actualmente un array con todos los nombre de las ciudades de España, el problema es que al ordenarlos, como hay varias ciudades que empiezan por tilde, me las pone al final del array.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto pasa de igual forma en el resto de ciudades. Por ejemplo en las que empiezan por la letra "M", "Málaga" la coloca al final de las que empiezan por esa letra.

¿Hay alguna forma de ordenar teniendo en cuenta las tildes?

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
    public List<City> getCities() {
        String query = "SELECT id, nombre_ciudad FROM ciudades";
        PreparedStatement sentence;
        ResultSet result;
        List<City> citiesList = new ArrayList<City>();
        
        log.info("Getting cities...");
        try {
            City city;
            sentence = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            result = sentence.executeQuery();
            
            while (result.next()) {
                city = new City(result.getInt(1), result.getString(2));
                citiesList.add(city);
            }
            
            Collections.sort(citiesList, new Comparator<City>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(City o1, City o2) {
                    return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
                }
            });
            
            log.info("Cities obtained: " + citiesList.size());

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error("An error has occurred: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return citiesList;  
    }
```

En él, hago una llamada a la base de datos, que es de donde saco todas las ciudades.

Comment: Es que en valor ascii las letras con acento están bastante más al final, por ejemplo la `a` tiene un valor decimal 97, mientras que la `á` tiene un valor de 160. Es decir, las letras con acento y otros caracteres raros van *después* de las letras *normales*. Para evitar eso podrías hacer varias cosas, en este caso en el `Comparator`, antes de hacer el `.compareTo()` podrías eliminar todos los acentos sustituyéndolos por las letras *sin acento*

Comment: Sí, es exactamente lo que estaba buscando! Mil gracias! No me había salido esta pregunta por internet...